# DOS batch file to move files with a given word in their name

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a collection of files in one directory in Windows, for example:

```
"file 01 WP2001.pdf"
"file 02 WP2012.pdf"
"file 03 AR2009.pdf"
```

I'd like to move all files with the string "WP" (case sensitive) in the their name (that is, files 01 and 02) to an existing folder.

Comment: That's right, Windows and case sensitive. Thanks, should have been clearer.

Comment: Assuming NTFS, most Win32 apps will not be able to distinguish between the files if they are the same name but different cases, and I suspect `copy` is affected by this.

Comment: create the backup of pdf files and try the batch.

Comment: Thanks Vinod. That seems to move all pdf files indiscriminately not just the ones with WP. I tried to append your code with the findstr command but I can't seem to get it to do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

From within a batch file

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b^|find "WP"') do move /Y "%%F" "someFolder"
```

If run from the command line, then change %%F to %F

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

If you have created the Directories already use this code

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a c=0
FOR %%i in (WP*.pdf) do (
set /a c=c+1
move "%%i" "file 0"!c!
)
endlocal
```

If you have **not** created Directories use this code

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a c=0
FOR %%i in (WP*.pdf) do (
set /a c=c+1
md "file 0"!c!
move "%%i" "file 0"!c!
)
endlocal
```

1. Paste this code in notepad and save as batch file
2. Copy the batch file to directory where your pdf files and directories are present.
3. Now Click on Batch file.Done.

Answer (score 0):

If the names of the files you need to copy follow the same pattern (`file`, followed by a space, followed by two characters, followed by a space followed by `WP`, followed by four characters, followed by the `.pdf` extension), you could use this single `COPY` command:

```
COPY "source_directory\file ?? WP????.pdf" "destination_directory"
```

Comment: Windows copy is not case sensitive. The OP expressly asked for the copy to be case sensitive. (A very odd request, since Windows file names are not case sensitive) Also, all the examples follow the pattern you specified, but the actual question just asks for file names containing "WP". Not sure what the actual requirement is.

Comment: Yes, it was my assumption that all the names needed to follow the same pattern, and I should have specified that immediately. Updating my answer now. As for case (in)sensitivity, I remember reading somewhere that Windows can operate in case-sensitive mode, it's just that by default it is case-insensitive and switching to case-sensitive mode should be done with care.